# C# Excel Late Binding set Cellvalues with Database

Tags: c#, excel, com

i have an interresting problem, due to an rewrite of my export i ran in some troubles.
With the code below i try to fill an splitted Range in my Excelworkbook.
The Result is realy strange, the first part of the Range ( tpl_p1 ) is filled right,
but the second part is filled very strange see screenshot.

```
openExcel(@"C:\bla\test.xlsx", "Tabelle1");
ArrayList posData = new ArrayList();
int lines = 30;
string[,] fo = new string[lines, 7];
for (int a = 0; a < lines; a++)
{
    fo[a, 0] = "1";
    fo[a, 1] = "2";
    fo[a, 2] = "3";
    fo[a, 3] = "4";
    fo[a, 4] = "5";
    fo[a, 5] = "6";
    fo[a, 6] = "7";
}
int i = 0;
object rng;
object[] rgums = new Object[1]; // { "A1:C70","E1:H70" };
object[] argums = new Object[1];
rgums[0] = "tpl_p1;tpl_p2";
try
{
    rng = Sheet.GetType().InvokeMember("Range", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, Sheet, rgums);
    argums[0] = 1;
    rng.GetType().InvokeMember("Select", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, rng, null);
    argums[0] = fo;
    rng.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, rng, argums);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    createErrorReport(ex, "Com");
}
```

And here the Result in Excel:
[Result](http://old.binarydigit.at/excel_prob.jpg)

I do not understand why the Array gets destroyed in the second part of the Range.